# Android 2.1 tts dialog

Tags: android, text-to-speech

How do I invoke dialog than allows user select default tts engine from code. Using tutorial on developer.android.com I achieved only that it uses internal pico. I'd like to use svox/TTS extended.

On 2.2 phones default engine can be selected in setting but on my 2.1 android it's not possible.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install "TTS Extended" app at [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.tts&feature=search_result)